# Looping on an array by Overlapping Windows

Tags: python, overlap, sliding-window

I have a numpy array:

```
seq = np.array(range(1,31))

In [24]: seq
Out[24]: array([ 1,  2,  3, ..., 28, 29, 30])
```

I would like to partition it into overlapping (or non overlapping) segments of length n.

```
n=7
overlap = 3
windowed_seq = windowing(seq,n,overlap)

In [24]: windowed_seq
Out[24]: [ 1,  5,   ...,    17, 21, 
           2,  6,   ...,    18, 22, 
           3,  7,   ...,    19, 23, 
           4,  8,   ...,    20, 24, 
           5,  9,   ...,    21, 25, 
           6,  10,  ...,    22, 26, 
           7,  11,  ...,    23, 27]
```

The last column:

```
25,
26,
27,
28,
29,
30,
31,
?]
```

Is omitted because one element is missing to complete the window..

I found this solution on the internet, but it does not work with array...

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch19s08.html

```
import itertools
def windows(iterable, length=2, overlap=0):
    it = iter(iterable)
    results = list(itertools.islice(it, length))
    while len(results) == length:
        yield results
        results = results[length-overlap:]
        results.extend(itertools.islice(it, length-overlap))
    if results:
        yield results
if _ _name_ _ == '_ _main_ _':
    seq = 'foobarbazer'
    for length in (3, 4):
        for overlap in (0, 1):
            print '%d %d: %s' % (length, overlap,
                    map(''.join, windows(seq, length, overlap)))
```

Could you help me making it working for my array?

Comment: can you show an input with expected output?

Comment: @NoobEditor I edited the question with the expected output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use scikit image's [`view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows):

```
import skimage
import numpy

data = numpy.arange(1, 31)
print skimage.util.view_as_windows(data, 7, step=3).T
```

yields

```
[[ 1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22]
 [ 2  5  8 11 14 17 20 23]
 [ 3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24]
 [ 4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25]
 [ 5  8 11 14 17 20 23 26]
 [ 6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27]
 [ 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28]]
```

If you want to make sure your array is exactly a multiple of your windowlength you can use

```
data = numpy.append(data, numpy.repeat(numpy.nan, len(data) % 7))
```

after which your output becomes

```
[[  1.   4.   7.  10.  13.  16.  19.  22.  25.]
 [  2.   5.   8.  11.  14.  17.  20.  23.  26.]
 [  3.   6.   9.  12.  15.  18.  21.  24.  27.]
 [  4.   7.  10.  13.  16.  19.  22.  25.  28.]
 [  5.   8.  11.  14.  17.  20.  23.  26.  29.]
 [  6.   9.  12.  15.  18.  21.  24.  27.  30.]
 [  7.  10.  13.  16.  19.  22.  25.  28.  nan]]
```

Comment: super! Thank you!